# SSL Certificate verification fails: Using OpenSSL

Tags: c++, c, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am using this code:

```
void check_cert(SSL* ssl)
{

//ssl initiation
SSL_library_init();
SSL_load_error_strings();
const SSL_METHOD *meth;
meth = SSLv3_method();
SSL_CTX *ctx;
SSL *_ssl;
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(meth);
int result = 0;
//getting the CA certificate

result = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx1, "cacert.pem", NULL);
//result = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, NULL, "/home/cdac/Desktop/test/cert");
printf("\nCA load result = %d", result);

//_ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx1, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);

SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx1, 1);
int result_long = SSL_get_verify_result(ssl);
printf("\nCertificate Check Result: %d", result_long);
if (SSL_get_verify_result(ssl) != X509_V_OK)
    {
        printf("\nCertiticate Verification Failed\n");
        //exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nCertiticate Verification Succeeded");
    }
}
```

cacert.pem is the CA certificate.
When i execute this I get this:

```
CA load result = 1
Certificate Check Result: 20
Certiticate Verification Failed
```

Code 20 means:

```
X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY: unable to get local issuer certificate

the issuer certificate could not be found: this occurs if the issuer certificate of an untrusted certificate cannot be found.
```

So can anyone help me? Where this fails?

The CA certificate is loading fine. (The load result returns 1).

Comment: Is this a self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you are getting a Root CA from the peer side and that Root CA is not loaded on the your side.